# how to make multivalues textbox which autocompletes from database in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

is there any way to make a textbox in c# winforms which takes multiple inputs which are autocompleted from database as shown in image.

[image]

Comment: @mohsen i am asking about to manage multiple values in one text which is selected by autosuggestion from database

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own AutocompleteTextBoxControl and then use it wherever you want. As example: 
[Custom textbox control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9247756/custom-textbox-control)

Or just use telerik control instead: 
http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/editors/autocompletebox/auto-complete